# Application is going in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiimageview, core-animation

My Application is in ARC.
In any view of my application there is one back ground image and on that image some animations are continuously repeating the images.

**Problem is : My application is going in background after some time.**

I seen and tried Lots of thing on stack, google and on apple doc but didn't got satisfactory solution.
I have Three Question.
(1) How to Stop this ?
(2) Is there any other method to release the memory manually in ARC.
(3) If i use [self.view removeFromSuperview]; for UIView then also some memory didn't released in ARC ?

MyCode for Animation is

```
imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy08" ofType:@"png"]];
[self.view addSubview:imgBubbleAnimation];

imageview.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy01" ofType:@"png"]],
                                      [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy02" ofType:@"png"]],
                                      [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy03" ofType:@"png"]],
                                      [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy04" ofType:@"png"]],
                                      [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy05" ofType:@"png"]],
                                      [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy06" ofType:@"png"]],
                                      [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy07" ofType:@"png"]],
                                      nil];
[imageview setAnimationRepeatCount:0]; // 0 for continuous
imageview.animationDuration =3.0;
[imageview startAnimating];
```

And Sound files are (played when particular button clicked)

```
URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                 pathForResource:@"ect1a" ofType:@"mp3"]];
audioSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL error:nil];
audioSound.delegate = self;
audioSound.volume = 5.0;
audioSound.numberOfLoops = 0;
[audioSound play];
```

I have 15 small sound files for one view and 15 animations for one view.
In every particular Animation there are min 15 images.
Any help, suggestion, link or tutorial are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mean the background or does the device go to sleep/idle (turns off the screen)?

If it is about going idle then try

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

when your animation starts. You should set it off (NO) again, when the animation is finished.

Comment: I tried this it's not working and I didn't use timer bro. i just code whole thing in viewDidLoad. and application got stopped and goes in back ground. do you have any idea about how to release memory of animation manually in ARC. it'll great help

Comment: That does not require you to use timers to work. It prevents the app from going to sleep. (Not background. Background is something different)

Comment: You release objects in ARC by making sure that noting (strong) refers to it. nil all references and remove the objects from arrays or nil the reference to the array etc.

Comment: I used it first. and my application (aka Game) is in 21 module (stage). it's a memory problem. ya it's in ARC but i am getting the memory error not app going to sleep. but thanks for your help...